# database design and structure for university study plan

Tags: database, database-design, relational-database, database-schema

i want to create a tabel for study plan for each major where students can see the study plan and mark the courses that he finished . How is the structure will be  ? 
i thought of this but its simple and not covering all the details .I need more table illustrating but how ?

```
  CREATE TABLE Studyplan(
     StudyplanID INTEGER(25) PRIMARY KEY,
     unicourses VARCHAR(25) ,
     majorcourses VARCHAR(25),
     electivecourses VARCHAR(25),
     Year INTEGER(200)
```

);

Comment: Is this homework? Presumably they gave you a brief/spec; work through it, spotting the nouns. They're probably going to be attributes or entities. Adjectives will be entities. Work out how the entities relate to one another, and what features describe those relationships. Post your thoughts as you go, if you'd like, and we might be able to give more feedback. Don't be afraid to have multiple tables!!

Comment: not HW i have to create website and that is part of the process. What is the attribute ? i define it as unicourses ,majorcourses,electivecourses .What is the entity ? "what features describe those relationships" you mean i have to draw ERD for that ?

Comment: If an ERD helps you picture this, sure, draw an ERD. Many people find the visual useful. Then ask yourself "is X data stored in this, or am I missing entities/attributes/relationships?" repeatedly. For example, with your current design; "is it possible to store student data in this design? no? should i add a student attribute/entity?".

Answer (score 1):

As this might be homework, I won't create the tables, but here are some pointers.

- With the StudyPlanID key, you are essentially saying that a particular study plan consists of one unicourse (whatever that is), one major course and one elective. Might a study plan consist of several of each type of course?
- Are these courses (uni, major, elective) listed in separate tables or all in one comprehensive Courses table? (After all, a particular course may be a "major" course for some majors and an elective for others.) Also, suppose a simple study plan consists of one uni, one elective and two major courses. That would require two entries, each with the same uni and elective data repeated. For these reasons, wouldn't it be better to have just one course reference per tuple, with a flag showing if it is uni, elective or major?

Well, I had a couple more listed, but this should be enough to keep you going for awhile. You can post other questions as you progress.

Comment: one course reference per tuple, with a flag showing if it is uni, elective or major?"  what is the reference ?how its ? can u give source illustrating it ? how is the flag in the table?

Comment: You have a table that contains courses. You have a table that lists the fields of study to major or minor in. You relate the two with an intersection table that will show the courses for each field required as a major, a minor or available as an elective. So Statistics 203 may be required if majoring in Math or minoring in Economics or available as an elective for Computer Science. That would be three entries for that one course. Since the Major/Minor/Elective flag describes the relationship, it would be a field in that table.

Comment: University courses(table),


Study plan("show the courses for each field required as a major "table),  


students(table)the attribute is 
GPA
Major
Year
Total hour
Name.


i will not divide the study plan to minor,major and elective . i thought to divide it based on the total hour that students finished and based on major . for example  if students finish 30 hours  he have to take Psychology  ,calculus,science. Right ?